# Window doesn't appear when using while loop

Tags: c++, qt, while-loop

I am making something in QT in C++.

However, when I am using a `while(1)` loop in the code, the window never appears. I tried many things, such as adding a `QApplication::processEvents();` at the end of the loop, but it doesn't work. There is no window.

How do get the window to appear?

Example code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent, Qt::WindowFlags flags) : QMainWindow(parent, flags) {
    _ui.setupUi(this);

while(1){
}

}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should paste some code so we can see.

Comment: Adding `QMainWindow::show();` before the loop and `QApplication::processEvents();` in the loop solves this problem, but the window doesn't close.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why you shouldn't block the event loop in a GUI program.

Comment: Why do you want to use while(1)? Maybe you can move what's happening in the loop to another thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every widget constructor should never block the main message loop!

The main message loop looks usually like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w(nullptr);
    w.show();
    int r = a.exec();
    return r
}
```

In your case your `MainWindow` ctor never returns, so `w.show()` is never called and `a.exec()` (main messgae loop) is never executed.

Not only blocking may be a problem in main window ctor, but also signals that are generated before main message loop is executed gets never raised. For an example establishment of an TCP/IP connection within main window ctor will never raise the `connected()` signal and associated slots. *1

*At least if the creation of the main window is before the main message loop is executed like in 99% the cases.*

Answer (score 0):

You must invalidate the window rectangle and yield so that the paint message is processed; then continue in the while loop; or just code a progress bar window.