# How to properly using infinite loop in Qt GUI?

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi

I am new to and learning the Qt GUI framework.

I have an ultrasonic sensor wired up to the Raspberry Pi, to measure water level. If I were coding in C, I would have used a `while(1)` loop to constantly read the sensor input. But when I put `while(1)` inside MainWindow.cpp, **the window cannot be displayed**. However, using `qDebug()` I can still print out the sensor value, which means my `while(1)` still running but the main window won't appear. I found out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45411094/5055747) that because of `while(1)`,

> `MainWindow` ctor never returns, so `w.show()` is never called and `a.exec()` (main message loop) is never executed.

To solve this, I use `QTimer` instead of a loop: connect the `timeout()` SIGNAL to a SLOT which is a function to read the sensor value one-time:

```
waterLevelTimer = new QTimer(this);
connect(waterLevelTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(getWaterLevel()));
waterLevelTimer->start(100); // "loop" once every 100 millisecond
```

With this method, I can read the sensor value with the fastest interval is 1 millisecond and the GUI still displayed fine.

But should I use `QTimer` to mimic a `while(1)` loop? Is there a better way to have an infinite loop to read GPIOs while still being able to use GUI for other work?

Comment: You should *never* have infinite loops in event-driven program (which basically all GUI programs are). And a constructor should really only initialize an object, not perform work.

Comment: And the solution you your problem *is* a timer, not an infinite loop. As a possible secondary solution you might be able to use a worker-thread but that could add other complications with synchronization and communication between the GUI and the thread.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Where should I put my work-performing code? I followed several Qt beginner examples and they all code inside MainWindow.cpp.

Comment: If you need to do something at periodic intervals a timer (`QTimer`) is perfect, that's what it's for. It's bettern than an infinite loop where you call `sleep` or something similar.

Comment: Can `QTimer` handle one-hour long interval?

Comment: Timers can be as long as the underlying operating-system can handle I presume. So one hour on a PC-like system would probably not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thread where the GUI of Qt runs never should be blocked by long-lasting operations like an infinite while-loop, because otherwise you would block the event system and nothing will work anymore.

Instead you usually create a worker thread in parallel (see QThread) where you do your loop in the run function of the thread. Maybe also use such timer as you suggest, which works if the executed code is faster than the timer duration.

```
QThread *thread = QThread::create([]{
    while(1)
        checkSomething();
});
thread->start();
```

Comment: QThread seems perfect for me. But your last sentence, what will happen if the work takes longer than the timer's interval?

Comment: If the timer triggers faster than the executed code takes, it will lead to congestion